# Do the College Scorecard's debt amount variables include only debt among students who borrowed?

Tags: collegescorecard

Do the College Scorecard's debt amount variables represent debt among only students who borrowed, or debt among all students (whether they borrowed or not)?

Answer (score 1):

Scorecard's debt amount variables describe only borrowers